# Anthos MCI: How to apply FrontendConfig for redirectToHttps annotation in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-anthos

I encountered an issue when i plan to disable http or another word set a redirection from http to https. However doing that comes with two options generally.

Use annotation as below inside "kind: ingress"

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

Or go with option like

1. create FrontendConfig
2. refer that FrontendConfig inside gke ingress as

   networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "my-config"

Hence for this to use i have to use apiVersion inside ingress as

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
```

Or

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
```

but the problem is cyclic, i cann't use "apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1" inside ingress because it does not support "FrontendConfig" also i cann't use "apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1" as it does not support "kind: MultiClusterIngress"

Expected

**FrontendConfig**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: myfrontend
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: PERMANENT_REDIRECT
  sslPolicy: "mypolicy"
```

**Ingress**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
# networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
metadata:
  name: my-mci-ingress
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
      networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "myfrontend"
      networking.gke.io/static-ip: 99.99.9.9
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      backend:
      .........
```

Need your suggestion if there is any possible solutions to set http re-direction for MultiClusterIngress in GKE.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @pankaj singh
GKE `MultiClusterIngress` as of now doesn't support the means for a `HTTP->HTTPS` redirect _(i.e there is no FrontEndConfig in MCI)_. Hopefully it will be out soon. The best option for now would be to handle the redirect via the application with a `30X` response for `HTTP` requests.

Comment: Thanks @Shabirmean. Yes, you are right. I see this is not yet supported for MCI https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features . Do you have any information like when it may (~tentative) be available.